# Creating an ephemeral SSL / TLS socket using a fresh key pair

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate

Every tutorial I have found explains how to create an SSL/TLS connection with `SSLSocket`s using a keystore file and truststore to store an SSL certificate after creating it manually with the keytool utility.

I would love to know how to do the same thing but with a public key/certificate generated on the fly (ephemeral).

It's so easy to create an RSA/EC key pair in Java so why can't we just use it for an `SSLSocket` as well? This has two big advantages in my opinion: it allows for forward secrecy and at the same time I don't have to deal with passwords, utilities, file readers and keystore converters for Android.

Comment: SSL/TLS already supports ephemeral asymmetric cryptography. All you need to is for both sides to support one of the ephemeral ciphersuites, e.g. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. Though this does not do away with "...passwords, utilities, file readers..." etc. even one iota.

Comment: You could create an ephemeral key pair and certificate, but what would be the point? Nobody would trust it.

Comment: I've removed the last part of your question as it is a separate question, and as question it is **way** to broad. @EJP is correct of course, you cannot use unsigned, ephemeral keys for authentication, even if they work great for key establishment (as ECDHE and DHE demonstrate).

Comment: Generating two random primes of half the key size is terribly inefficient. It will also result in an undefined running time as the algorithm doesn't know when it will find a prime. You **really** don't want to use RSA key generation to create ephemeral key pairs.

Comment: Although generating a DSA keypair (given pre-created parameters) or ECDSA keypair (TLS practically always uses standardized thus pre-created 'curves') is fast. But as answered they aren't certified. @MaartenBodewes

Answer (score 3):

> This has two big advantages in my opinion: it allows for forward secrecy

Forward secrecy typically deals with the key agreement like ECDHE or DHE (though the latter is now widely deprecated due to logjam).

It *is* good practice to re-key certificates from time to time, though a new one for every TLS session is not necessary.

> It's so easy to create an RSA/EC key pair in Java so why can't we just use it for an SSLSocket as well?

You need an X509 certificate too, not a just a key. You can still make those on the fly, but you are going to have to sign the certificate. Either the certificate will be self signed, or you need a certificate authority that can sign certificates very quickly, on demand. Practically, the latter doesn't exist and would mean very slow handshakes.

If the certificate is self-signed, browsers or any other user agent will not know how to trust the certificate, and using a self signed certificates severely impacts the use of TLS.

Answer (score 2):

As a technically correct but fairly useless alternative:

TLS actually defines 'anonymous' keyexchange methods [DH_anon](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-F.1.1.1) and [ECDH_anon](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-2.5) (and ciphersuites using them) which do forward-secret key agreement using ephemeral keypairs, and NO authentication, thus not requiring any certificate or keystore on the server or (potentially) truststore on the client.

Being unauthenticated, they are easily vulnerable to active attack, and thus people (and authorities) who actually want security consider them unacceptable for use. Java (JSSE) does implement them, but does not enable them by default; your code must call `.setEnabledCiphers` with an appropriately modified or set list. Most other SSL/TLS implementations either similarly disable them or don't implement them at all.

But technically that is a valid way to do TLS with no long-term keys and certs, and thus no manual effort for adminstering them.

As an aside, I *believe* this is why creating an (`SSLContext` and) `SSLSocketFactory` with (`KeyManager` for) a keystore not containg a valid privateKeyEntry does not give an error, because in principle it could create sockets (or engines) used for anonymous connections. Instead, since in practice anonymous keyexchange is never used, these factories cause all subsequent connections to fail in a fashion many nonexpert programmers have trouble diagnosing. (In contrast trying to create a validator for an empty truststore throws a specific exception, something like 'trust anchor set must not be empty'.)

**update:** later in 2018 TLS 1.3 removed this option, always requiring server authentication either with a certificate or a pre-shared key (PSK), and Java/JSSE does not implement user-configurable PSK. (1.3 also replaces the former session resumption method with a forward-secret version using automatically-configured ephemeral PSKs, which JSSE does implement.) OTOH in 2023 1.2 is still widely implemented and substantially used, although 1.0 and 1.1 (like SSL2 and SSL3 earlier) have been prohibited by many authorities and largely vanished.