# Is server-side certificate mandatory for SSL connection using OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, server, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am having a C client-server model that established an SSL connection using openssl library. On the server-side, I have set the verification mode to `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` and hence, the client certificates are being verified on the server-side on the basis of the CAs added to the store.

On the client-side, however, I have enabled `SSL_VERIFY_NONE`, and thus there is no verification of the server certificates on the client-side, and the SSL connection is established irrespective of whichever SSL certificate the server sends.

However, when I'm not sending any certificate from the client, the connection does not pass. The errors that I am getting are -

- On the server-side: `140510060005296:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1435:`
- On the client-side: `140575466600368:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40`

Why is this so? Is it mandatory for the server to have a certificate even if it is not validated?

Comment: TLS encryption is bootstrapped by the server public key, which is a part of the server certificate. No certificate = no encryption

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: that's incorrect. TLS keyexchange can be done without a cert -- with PSK for auth (as Steffen correctly said) although few apps use this, or on 1.2 and below with NO authentication by '[EC]DH_anon' (anonymous) suites, although these are usually disabled and even fewer apps use them.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183544/creating-an-ephemeral-ssl-tls-socket-using-a-fresh-key-pair#50201790 and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10680/ssl-encryption-and-ssl-certificates/ and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61340/ssl-server-certificate-optional

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  it is also possible to run TLS in reverse, where the client acts as the TLS server. Your comment is completely incorrect.

Comment: There is a slight misunderstanding here. You *can* use SSL in a way that does not require a server certificate. After all, the null cipher is always a possibility. It just doesn't work with your typical default setup.

Answer (score 1):

The server certificate is used to verify the identity of the server. Verifying the server identity is a MUST since otherwise some man in the middle attacker could simply claim the role of the server. In this case the connection would still be encrypted from the perspective of the client - but the data would be securely exchanged not with the intended server but with the attacker instead.

While there are other ways to verify the server identity (like [PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK)) using certificates is the most established one. Which authentication method is actually used to verify the server identity is part of the cipher specification (at least up to TLS 1.2, in TLS 1.3 this is handled differently).

A client will offer a list of ciphers to the server, which then picks one it can support. Typically the client offers ONLY ciphers which require either RSA or ECC certificate based authentication, since most clients don't support any other kind of server authentication. If the server has no certificate configured it cannot support any of these offered ciphers - resulting in "no shared ciphers" error.

SSL_VERIFY_NONE does not change what ciphers are offered by the client, it only does not verify the server certificate (which as I already said is a bad idea).

Comment: In 1.3 _some_ server auth is literally a 2119-type MUST (required for conformance to the standard); in lower protocols there is a capability for unauthenticated 'anonymous' handshake, but it is a bad idea because MitM (as you say) and therefore it is very rarely used, and relevant to this Q it also _prevents_ client auth.